# Notice: Undefined index: label

Tags: php, magento

I have this annoying error:

```
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: label  in /var/www/html/www.mysite.com/prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 367
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array does not contain an item with the index 'label', so PHP spits out this error.

For example:

```php
// Works fine.
$i = array();
$i['label'] = "My Value";

echo $i['label'];
```

But this however, which is what your code is doing, will not work.

```php
$i = array();
$i['somerandomlabel'] = "My Value";

echo $i['label'); // Will fail, 'label' in $i is never set
```

Examine your code and make sure you actually set 'label' at some point in time.

Comment: Hello,thank you for you help. Please note that I transfers some data between 2 DB since this my cart page show a white content. http://www.cipc.com/checkout/cart/. You think it's related?

Comment: I doubt it, this type of error is directly a programmers error. Either you should be using an index that isn't 'label', or you forgot to actually add the element 'index' to the array